# How can I host ASP.NET API and Blazor Web Assembly like an JavaScript-SPA?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, single-page-application, blazor, asp.net-blazor

**Context:**

We want to create a Single Page Application that runs with Blazor WebAssembly on the client-side. On the server-side, the solution has an ASP.NET MVC which includes some ApiController classes for our REST APIs.

We want to use ASP.NET API on the server-side instead of Blazor Server because we want to provide a REST interface with ApiController classes for unknown consumers.

Here is my client-side (Blazor WebAssembly) and server-side (ASP.NET API) project in a single solution:

[image]

[image]

A first try to request the API via Blazor´s HttpClient-class in our `FetchData`-component:

```
@inject HttpClient Http
...
@code {
    private TodoItem[] TodoItems;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        TodoItems = await Http.GetJsonAsync<TodoItem[]>("api/ToDo");
    }
}
```

On server-side the API-Controller looks like:

```
namespace ToDoListAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    public class ToDoController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public string IGetAll() 
        {
            var lResult = new List<ToDoList.TodoItem>();

            // create dummies
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                lResult.Add(new ToDoList.TodoItem() { Title = $"Title {i}", IsDone = false });
            }

            return JsonSerializer.Serialize(lResult);
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem:** In my Blazor WebAssembly Project the request to the API fails. The Blazor WebAssembly Project is hosted via https://localhost:44340/ and the API is hosted via https://localhost:44349/. How can I host both projects together as I would it do with a JavaScript Framework?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can either, depending on how you want to host and deploy your solution :

**API and application in 2 different hosts**

[Enable CORS in the API project Startup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1) class :

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    ...
    app.UseCors(configure => 
    {
         // configure here your CORS rule
    }
    ...
}
```

**All in one host**

In your API project

- add a package reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server`
- Setup the blazor server in your `Startup` class

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
    ...
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => 
   {
       endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
       endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
   });
}
```

You can create a sample solution with : `dotnet new blazorwasm --hosted`. It'll create a solution with a Blazor wasm project and a host.

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: Why do you suggest an Blazor-Server when I want to have an RESTful Server API with ASP.NET Core API?

Comment: it's not a blazor server, it's the server for your Blazor wasm application.

Comment: Exactly what I do in [MyStartup](https://github.com/aguacongas/TheIdServer/blob/master/src/Aguacongas.TheIdServer/Startup.cs) for [theidserver.herokuapp.com](https://theidserver.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: When I execute your suggested cmd 'dotnet new bazorwasm --hosted' then I get the following error 'No templates matched the input template name: bazorwasm'.

Comment: install the SDK 3.1.300, that should include blazorwasm template https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/get-started?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=netcore-cli

Comment: The "All in one host" was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: All in one host (or hosted Blazor webassembly as it is called by Microsoft) can be created by selecting the hosted checkbox when creating the project ([MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/tooling?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=windows)). This sets up a Blazor webassembly, Api and shared class library project, hosted from one location. Perfect.

Answer (score 11):

With the latest update to the templates `dotnet new -i Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Templates::3.2.0-preview2.20160.5`

You can create a Blazor WebAssembly app setup with authentication using ASP.NET Core Identity and IdentityServer by running the following command:

`dotnet new blazorwasm --hosted --auth Individual -o BlazorAppWithAuth1`

This creates:

- Client Side Blazor
- A **single** Project that can be used for MVC, API and razor pages, that contains an "inline" IdentityServer which can be used to secure the API calls

I was stuck on how to have IS4 in the same project as the APi (it's a small project and a independently hosted IDP would be overkill and I just want to deploy one thing) but this template shows how.

source: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/blazor-webassembly-3-2-0-preview-2-release-now-available/

Comment: Did this change with .NET 8?