# How to convert a Blazor Server app to standalone WebAssembly app?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to change my Blazor Server app to a Web Assembly app. I thought the standalone (not hosted) version of WebAssembly is more suitable for my needs. But I can't figure out how I can transfer this code from Startup.Configure to the Program.Main

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
});
```

Any advice on that?

Comment: Is that answer your question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61012208/2940908

Comment: @agua from mars, thanks, I see you are recommending a hosted version there, and I was thinking if I could use a standalone version

Comment: Sure you can, you just need to reference it in your host by project reference or package reference

Comment: @agua from mars, and then I'll have to configure endpoints in the host, right?

Comment: As it is described in this answer, yes