# Is it possible to add Blazor WebAssembly without a Router and putting it inside an existing ASP.NET Core website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

It's similar to [this question: Include a Blazor Webassembly project into an existing ASP.NET Core project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63723998/include-a-blazor-webassembly-project-into-an-existing-asp-net-core-project) but my scenario is different:

- I already have an ASP.NET Core website https://www.example.com with many pages.
- I now want to add a page like `Feature.cshtml` at https://www.example.com/feature, which has content like this:

```html
<!-- Other content: header, texts, etc -->

<app>
    Blazor app here
</app>

<!-- Other content: more text, footer, scripts, etc -->
```

The Blazor app does not need to know about the URL, I will just use it for nice Component features, similar to Web Component.

Can I achieve this? If possible, without a separte Blazor WebAssembly project but it's okay if I have to. Also would be great if I can host more than one app (at https://www.example.com/feature1 and https://www.example.com/feature2) on a website.

Comment: Why do you want to load single pages in Web Assembly?  You have to load WASM everytine.  Slow.  Why not use Server?  The page just loads the page component, missing out the router.  Can show you an example if you wish.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis SEO is one come to mind. I know there is server-rendering but that also doesn't justify moving everything to Blazor Server when your ASP.NET Core website is already stable. Also IMO even if I start anew, I wouldn't use Blazor Server because it uses a lot of server's resources (keeping RTC connection alive, ...) while serving HTML is perfectly fine.

Comment: Agreed, but the problem with loading each page as a WASM SPA is speed.  MS is working on speeding things up, but I'm not sure how fast they can make that initial page load.  If you're happy with the load speed then no problems.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis well the good thing about this is you can wrap the app with your own content (provided by standard HTML through ASP.NET). So you can have proper content and even good loading screen while Blazor Assemblies are being loaded. I still see this as an absolute win.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have successfully add a Blazor WebAssembly app to an existing ASP.NET Core app. You can check the [demo repository here on GitHub](https://github.com/datvm/DemoBlazorInsideWeb). I also wrote the detailed step-by-step instruction there.

[image]

## Step-by-step guide

### 1. Setup a new Blazor WebAssembly App (B)

- Create a new `Blazor WebAssembly App` project, for example `DemoBlazorInsideWeb.BlazorApp`.
- Update your router in `App.razor` to show the `Index` page for all routes:

```html
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <!-- Delete everything here -->
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <!-- Add this here -->
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <Index />
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

- Optionally delete `@page` in your `Index.razor` file so no URL can ever be routed to it. This is to prevent a route accidentally match it.
- Optionally delete `index.html` file in your `wwwroot` folder. However you may want to keep the content somewhere to copy its content later.

> **Note**
> You can still use Routing if you want to serve multiple apps on the same website (even though you have to pack all those apps inside this single project)

### 2. Setup your (existing) ASP.NET Core website (A)

- Add the Blazor project as Reference to your ASP.NET Core website project (A refers to or depends on B).
- Install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server` Nuget package:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server
```

- In your app startup (`Program.cs` or `Startup.cs`), add `app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles()` before `app.UseStaticFiles()`:

```cs
app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

- In order to debug WASM app, you need to:

  - Add `app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();` in Development environment:

    ```cs
    if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        // Usually the template has this block
    }
    else // And you add this block
    {
        app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
    }
    ```
  - Add `inspectUri` property to your `launchSettings.json` file (you should find it in `Properties` folder). Add it to whichever profile you use, `https` and/or `IIS Express`:

    ```json
    {
        // ...
        "IIS Express": {
            // ...
            "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}"
        }
    }
    ```

### 3. Setup the new web (Feature) page

In the ASP.NET Core Razor Page that you want to add the Blazor app, you need to setup Blazor's content

- Add the HTML and Javascript content:

```html
<!-- Other Razor code -->

<div id="app">
    <!-- Loading content before Blazor loads. You can copy it from index.html file -->
</div>

<div id="blazor-error-ui">
    An unhandled error has occurred.
    <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
    <a class="dismiss"></a>
</div>

<!-- Other Razor code -->

<!-- Add the script where relevant to your project -->
<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
```

- You should also refer to the Blazor's CSS file, or simply move its content to your own ASP.NET Core project:

```html
<!-- You need to have Heads section in your Layout -->
@section Heads {
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/app.css" />
}
```